# Do I need a property to bind server code to input events in Blazor?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

Here's what I imagine I need:

```html
<input type="text" @bind="this.ConceptSearch" @bind:event="oninput" />
```

```cs
@code {
    private string _ConceptSearch = "";
    private string ConceptSearch {
        get {
            return this._ConceptSearch;
        }
        set {
            this._ConceptSearch = value;
            this.PopulateSuggestions();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to cut out the middle man (the property) and just directly call some code?

Comment: `@oninput=SomeMethod`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ***@onchange*** instead of ***@bind*** to solve it